# Beamer with CambridgeUS theme: title in the footer does not fit

Tags: beamer, customize

I am using beamer with CambridgeUS theme. My problem is that, with the default settings, the title of the presentation, as it appears in the footer, does not fit, but just for a few letters. Below I report an example. How can I slightly enlarge the space for the central bar?

[image]

Comment: Please don't just post an image of your presentation. Always add a small, but compilable test document to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redefine the footline. By default, each box is `wd=.333\paperwidth` wide, but you can redistribute the ratios to whatever layout you want:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{some very long title which overflows the footline and needs some extra space}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.6\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,leftskip=2ex,rightskip=2ex,sep=0pt]{date in head/foot}%
    \hfill%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}%
    \insertshortdate{}%
    \hfill%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
    \usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]